# Scaling a PDF using Adobe Acrobat's preflight fixup doesn't scale document links with it

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, hyperlink, latex

## Overview

I've got a `LaTeX` document (example below) which has been typeset at `1.7x` `A4`-paper size (its final size is `357mm x 504.9mm`). However, I still want my final document to be `A4`-paper sized.

To achieve this, I tried using LaTeX at first by embedding the PDF into a new PDF file, which works with the scaling, but destroys the links. I've resolved to using Adobe Acrobat Pro (Version `2023.001.20174`) to scale my document using its available `Scale pages` preflight fixup. This scales the PDF just fine, but it loses the internal links (such as footnotes and footnote back-references) as they now start jumping to (seemingly) random views and not the target that they are supposed to go to.

Any ideas for this so that the links stay intact?

## Attachments

### `LaTeX` document (example)

```latex
% I've only included the packages relevant to the question.

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[margin=2cm, paperwidth=357mm, paperheight=504.9mm]{geometry}  % 1.7x A4-paper size (mm)

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[symbol=$\uparrow$]{footnotebackref}

\hypersetup{  % Stops links and references having a visible box around them.
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

    Here's some text with a footnote.\footnote{This is a footnote!}

\end{document}
```

### Preflight fixup configuration

[Preflight fixup configuration - Scale pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1hA0.png)

*P.S. I do not want any advice/writing philosophy on why the document shouldn't be scaled up in the first place. I just want to know how the links won't end up broken when the scaling is applied.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `cpdf -scale-to-fit a4portrait in.pdf -o out.pdf` should move the links and their destinations properly when scaling. If it doesn't, that's a bug, and you can send me a bug report with an example file here: https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still wondering if there is a way to do this type of scaling that preserves document links and such from inside Acrobat itself. But, seeing as this tool worked so far, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: I can only guess that, since it's part of "preflight", and links are irrelevant when printing, Adobe don't feel they should be altered. I too find it odd that there's not just a simple menu option in Acrobat to scale a document's pages.